# Final fantasy 6 Snes / Playstation

Tags: version-differences, final-fantasy-6

I've never really played Final Fantasy VI. I've tried a few times, but never cleared it entirely.

I'm a big RPG fan, and I want to make sure I get the best out of my first playthrough.  I've just never given this game a chance.

I bought it on the SNES and then realised it was released on Playstation afterwards.

Except for the cutscenes that look amazing on the playstation, are there any big differences I should be aware of before choosing ?

**I don't want opinions because this is not a shopping question.**

I want to know if a version has differences that alters the gameplay in anyway making it the cheap version (just like the PC version of Final Fantasy VII which was full of bugs and with disaster music).

So. Are there any **real differences** I should be aware of ?

Comment: you are going to have to reword this question so this doesn't sound too much like a shopping recommendation.  I'd suggest rewording to ask about various version differences for the game, then you can decide for yourself which one to play.

Comment: @spartacus I will. Although it is clearly stated that I don't want opinions. And I'm not asking for someone else to choose for me I just as stated here : Are there any big differences I should be aware of before choosing ? ... But still youre right I will change it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_VI#PlayStation)

> Final Fantasy VI's PlayStation re-release is very similar to the original Japanese release as seen on the Super Famicom. With the exception of the addition of two full motion video opening and ending sequences and new effects used for the start and end of battles, the **graphics, music and sound are left unchanged** from the original version. The only notable changes to gameplay (in addition to **loading times** not present in the cartridge versions) involve the **correction of a few software bugs** from the original and the addition of **a new "memo save" feature**, allowing players to quickly save their progress to the PlayStation's RAM.

(Emphasis mine)

So to summarize, the "game changing" differences are:

- PS version has loading time which weren't present on the SNES version.
- PS version has some bug fixes.
- PS version add a "quick save" feature (I assume it means making a temporary save to the RAM rather than to the memory card).

Answer (score -2):

You can find the console differences for this game, here: http://gamedifferences.com/final-fantasy-vi

Comment: You should probably summarize the information at the link, as if it ever goes down, this answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

Not 100% related, but a good thing about this (almost) exact port is that they leave some exploits open as well. Let's clarify it's not cheating or bugs. The one I used the most is the following:

- When an enemy is in invisible status, it becomes very vulnerable to magic. You can cast Death, Vanish, X-Zone and this kind of 1 hit magic and it will work 99% of the times. You can level up a lot in the Dinosaur Forest with this technique. I combined with an item that allows you two cast twice per turn and also another which reduces the cost of magic to 1 MP.

This is not working anymore on GBA version (it works but not with 99-ish% of accuracy).

Comment: At least let me know why the downvotes.